# Using Jquery/Javascript to delete elements based on dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has a dropdown menu and a few text fields. I would like the form to delete the text areas if one of the options from the dropdown menu is selected. Thus, if the Credit Card option is selected, only then will these four fields appear.

1. Card Number
2. CVV Code
3. Expiry Date
4. Name on Card

If no option or Paypal is selected, the above 4 fields should be removed. The reason why it is insufficient to hide them is that they are required fields so hiding alone them will not allow users to submit the form.

Below is the full code. As the code is messy, I have tidied it up here: https://jsfiddle.net/lindychen/ow8zq1y6/28/

Thank you.

```
  <label for="form-field-field_5" class="elementor-field-label">Payment Method</label>
  <div class="elementor-field elementor-select-wrapper ">
    <select name="form_fields[field_5]" id="form-field-field_5" class="elementor-field-textual elementor-size-sm" required="required" aria-required="true">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
      <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elementor-field-type-number elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_6 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_6" class="elementor-field-label">Card Number</label><input type="number" name="form_fields[field_6]" id="form-field-field_6" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Card Number" required="required" aria-required="true"> </div>

<div class="elementor-field-type-number elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_7 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_7" class="elementor-field-label">CVV Code</label><input type="number" name="form_fields[field_7]" id="form-field-field_7" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="CVV Code" required="required" aria-required="true"> </div>

<div class="elementor-field-type-date elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_8 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_8" class="elementor-field-label">Expiry Date</label><input type="text" name="form_fields[field_8]" id="form-field-field_8" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual elementor-date-field flatpickr-input" required="required" aria-required="true"> </div>

<div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_9 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_9" class="elementor-field-label">Name on card</label><input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_9]" id="form-field-field_9" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="NAME ON CARD" required="required" aria-required="true"> </div>
```

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to show relevant input fields according to the dropdown option selected? (eg. Paypal, Credit Card)

Comment: @SuhaibJanjua Yes your understanding is correct. That is what I want to do.

Comment: @wazz understood, thanks. I am out and don't have laptop in front of me. I would amend it once I reach home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly. You just want to show/hide Credit Card details with required fields on the basis of payment option selected. (e.g Credit Card)

Your jQuery selector hierarchic is not correct and there it is not working.
As you don't want to update your HTML/CSS. I have fixed your jQuery code. Working [JSFIDDLE is here](https://jsfiddle.net/suhaibjanjua/qhbszgpe/6/).

I have also updated the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form-field-field_5').change(function() {


    if ($('#form-field-field_5 option:selected').val().toString() === "Credit Card") {

      // Show credit card details
      $('.elementor-field-group-field_6, .elementor-field-group-field_7, .elementor-field-group-field_8, .elementor-field-group-field_9').show();

      // Add required attribute

      $('#form-field-field_6, #form-field-field_7, #form-field-field_8, #form-field-field_9').attr("required", "required");

    } else {
      // Hide credit card details
      $('.elementor-field-group-field_6, .elementor-field-group-field_7, .elementor-field-group-field_8, .elementor-field-group-field_9').hide();

      // remove required attribute

      $('#form-field-field_6, #form-field-field_7, #form-field-field_8, #form-field-field_9').removeAttr("required");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.elementor-field-type-number.elementor-field-group.elementor-column.elementor-field-group-field_6.elementor-col-100.elementor-field-required,
.elementor-field-type-number.elementor-field-group.elementor-column.elementor-field-group-field_7.elementor-col-100.elementor-field-required,
.elementor-field-type-date.elementor-field-group.elementor-column.elementor-field-group-field_8.elementor-col-100.elementor-field-required,
.elementor-field-type-text.elementor-field-group.elementor-column.elementor-field-group-field_9.elementor-col-100.elementor-field-required {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-field-type-select elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_5 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_5" class="elementor-field-label">Payment Method</label>
  <div class="elementor-field elementor-select-wrapper ">
    <select name="form_fields[field_5]" id="form-field-field_5" class="elementor-field-textual elementor-size-sm" required="required" aria-required="true">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
      <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elementor-field-type-number elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_6 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_6" class="elementor-field-label">Card Number</label><input type="number" name="form_fields[field_6]" id="form-field-field_6" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Card Number" required="required"
    aria-required="true"> </div>

<div class="elementor-field-type-number elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_7 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_7" class="elementor-field-label">CVV Code</label><input type="number" name="form_fields[field_7]" id="form-field-field_7" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="CVV Code" required="required"
    aria-required="true"> </div>

<div class="elementor-field-type-date elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_8 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_8" class="elementor-field-label">Expiry Date</label><input type="text" name="form_fields[field_8]" id="form-field-field_8" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual elementor-date-field flatpickr-input"
    required="required" aria-required="true"> </div>

<div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_9 elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
  <label for="form-field-field_9" class="elementor-field-label">Name on card</label><input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_9]" id="form-field-field_9" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="NAME ON CARD"
    required="required" aria-required="true"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I know if it is possible to carry this out without amending the HTML? The reason is that I will not have access to amending it.

Comment: @umek I have updated my answer. Without any modification in HTML/CSS you can still achieve your desire functionality by using the jQuery code that I shared. Working fiddles are available. Have a look now.

Comment: Many thanks Suhaib, that works great! However, the issue is that hiding the credit card fields alone will not work as users who select Paypal are unable to submit the form because the credit card details are marked as required fields. So even though the credit card details do not appear to someone who wants to pay by Paypal, the user cannot submit their form (since the credit card fields are still empty). Can you please help me out? Edited your code slightly to include relevant CSS. Thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/lindychen/vpw0j2Lm/2/

Comment: @umek I have updated the answer. You can simply add/remove required attribute from the required fields so that user can easily submit for PayPal payment without credit card required fields.

Comment: i have tried to do it but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this :

1. If other than credit card is selected hide the 4 fields + remove the required attribute form the input fields. `$('.elementor-field').attr('required',false);` This will allow the user to submit the form. (elementor-field I have taken this class just for example. You can add one separate class to the fields you want to hide )

   2. Instead of putting the input fields in html file you generate them dynamically based on the selection.
   3. Make two separate form and show and hide them based on the drop down selection

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like this:

- When you hide inputs remove Required (`$("#cvv").removeAttr("required");`)
- When you show inputs add Required (`$("#cvv").attr("required",true);`)

```js
$(function(){
  $("#selectState").on("change",function(){
    if (this.value==="show"){
      $("div#inputs").show();
      $("#cvv").attr("required",true);
      $("#cardno").attr("required",true);
    }else{      
      $("#cvv").removeAttr("required");
      $("#cardno").removeAttr("required");
      $("div#inputs").hide();
    }
  })
  
  $("#theForm").on("submit", function(){
    console.log("Submited");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="theForm">
    <div>
      <select id="selectState">
        <option value="show">
          Show
        </option>
        <option value="hide">
          Hide
        </option>
      </select>
      <div id="inputs">
      <br/>
      <input id="cvv" name="cvv" type="text" required/>
      <br/>
      <input id="cardno" name="cardno" type="text" required/>
      <br/>
      <input id="date" name="date" type="text" />
      </div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```